# Three.js raycast towards origin perpendicular vector left/right

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to raycast exactly towards the left from center and right from center.

My center vector would be origin.
Three.js raycaster takes direction as an parameter.

```
var origin = new THREE.Vector3();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
var near = 0;
var far = 100;
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(origin,direction,near,far);
```

From my understanding; If I wanted to get direction towards left from my origin would be a perpendicular vector from the origin. Not sure how I would do this in three.js
I am also not able to figure out camera rotation so it's always facing towards the direction of 2 vectors.

My overall goal is this outcome below:

[image]

From the point on the right(origin) - I want to raycast to the point on the left highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean left in screen space, I think you want `dir=new THREE.Vector3 (-1,0,0).applyQuaternion (camera.quaternion)`

Comment: Actually, not left in the screen space, but left from a given vector. A vector represents a mesh object, I'd like to raycast from that mesh object towards left/right.

Comment: Then dir is just Vector3 (-1,0,0)

Comment: You're mixing your terminology. A position is a point. A direction is a vector. (A point of distance 1 from 0,0,0)

Comment: Position is a vector too.